# Google Meet background Blur

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js, google-meet

I was curious of the new "turn on/off" [background blur functionality](http://jnack.com/blog/2020/09/17/google-meet-adds-background-blur-with-a-twist/) of Google Meet (currently in test). I have investigated a bit and it seems it is using **Tensorflow Lite** models:

```
segm_heavy.tflite
segm_lite.tflite
```

via **[WASM](https://webassembly.org/)**

```
mediapipe_wasm_simd.wasm
```

while the model graph should be

```
background_blur_graph.binarypb
```

The model seems works at the level of the `HTMLCanvasElement` as far as I can see. Anyone aware of a similar model?

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks to [Jason Mayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5627842/jason-mayes) and [Physical Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63069/physicaled) I was able to reproduce a very close background blur effect in the [Google's BodyPix demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix)

The settings of the application are showed in the Controls box. There is a `backgroundBlurAmount` option that let you customize the blur percentage to apply as well.

[image]

The result is almost close to the official Google Meet application.

[image]

Comment: Our Bodypix model can allow you to segment the human body and blur the background. https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

Comment: @JasonMayes thanks. I was looking at the Google’s Media Pipe that seems to use TF lite and have human body tracking. Is this the sane model you are referring to?

Comment: @loretoparisi I can answer that, we are experimenting with using body-pix. It is a different model with different capabilities than mediapipe. It has an excellent interface and a very good demo. Check it out by all means.

Comment: Indeed as PysicalEd said Bodypix is different. You can see demo of it here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

Comment: @loretoparisi, Is your issue resolved? If so, can you please post the solution in answer section for the benefit of the Community. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 thank you for the reminder. I will do with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

majority of segmentation models give alpha channel as a result (some give more, but alpha is most useful) - what is masked and what is not

so if you want to blur the background, its a multi-step process:

1. resize input to model expected size
2. run model to get alpha channel
3. resize output back to original size
4. draw original image on canvas
5. draw alpha channel over it so only foreground stays visible
   for example using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'darken'`
6. optionally blur it a bit since model output is never perfect
   for example using `ctx.filter =` blur(8px)`;

so if you want to blur the background, simply apply apply blur simply copy canvas from 4, apply blur on it and draw if back before going to step 5

regarding models, **google meet** is not bad but i had better results with **google selfie** model
bodypix is older model, great configurability but not that great results

example code: https://github.com/vladmandic/human/blob/main/src/segmentation/segmentation.ts

Comment: Thank you Vladimir it makes sense! Amazing library btw!